# Facebook long-lived accesstoken for a page

Tags: facebook, token

I'm using a facebook extension in TYPO3 to pull out the facebook posts of a page. Therefor I need the accesstoken. 
I googled around and found that I need a facebook app and I need to be administrator of the page.

Then I heard that I need to connet the app with the site, but how can I do this?

I also tried to get accesstoken:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials`

And then performing:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}`

... with this token but it says `No user access token specified`

Can someone help me step by step how to get the long lived token?

Comment: Do you just want to pull updates or would like to post also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you just want to pull, you really don't need a page access token. Until and unless you have a demographic or other restriction over your page. All the pages are Public and data over them can be easily accessed by using the [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) which is simply put

```
Your_App_ID|Your_App_Secret
```

Comment: so instead of the access_token I simply use the values of APP_ID|APP_SECRET? But how does the app know that it is for a page?

Comment: App doesn't knows, its just that when you use the page's id, it fetches the value from it. And as everything on it is public, you can get anything by just App ID

Comment: Okay, thanks (: Thats better than an access_token because I don't need to do something on expiration because this will never expire :D

Answer (score 0):

first u need to get an API key from facebook, so here are the steps--->

http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-acquire-your-facebook-api-key.html

& then u can access facebook API, these are docs provided by the facebook to use that API--->

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Comment: I have an API key and I read in the docs, thats where I have the urls for the requests above^^ But this doesnt really help me

Answer (score 0):

This was my implementation (PHP):

```
$newposts = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/YOURFBPAGE/feed&access_token=YOURAPPID|YOURAPPSECRET"));
```

Since I was only using this to make simple pull request of my feed posts this is the best way to do it. You don't have to deal with expiring access tokens. Just create your facebook App and get the ID and secret.